# Better way to refresh a custom control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, controls

I'm learning how to write custom control and manage and raise events.
I'have create a pointless custom control, a line you can add on main and decide size and color. I've made also an event to replace OnClick (I'm just learning) and I've called it MyClick. Here's the code

```
public class EditedLine : UserControl
{
    public delegate void LineClickEventHandler(object sender, EditedLineClickEventArgs e);

    [Description("Occurs when control is clicked")]
    public event LineClickEventHandler MyClick;

    private Color _color;
    private float _size;

    public EditedLine()
    {
        _color = Color.Black;
        _size = 3;
    }
    public EditedLine(Color color, float size)
    {
        _color = color;
        _size = size;
    }

    public Color LineColor
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set { _color = value; }
    }
    public float LineSize
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set { _size = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(_color, _size), new Point(0, 0), new Point(this.Size.Width, 0));
    }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        OnLineClick(new EditedLineClickEventArgs());
    }

    protected virtual void OnLineClick(EditedLineClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyClick != null)
        {
            MyClick(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

luckly everythings is working. I can see my control in the control toolbox and I can add to my project, even the event is working.
But, if inside MyClick i try to change the color of the Line, nothing happens.
I have to use this Proprieties intead of the ones before:

```
    public Color LineColor
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set { _color = value; this.Refresh();  }
    }
    public float LineSize
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set { _size = value; this.Refresh();  }
    }
```

So I'm asking myself if there is a better way to refresh the control. If I'm redrawing a single line is easy to be done, but if it is a more complex control? I thought to do a 'Redraw' private method but I don't know how to access the 'Graphic' object of the EditedLine istance. Is 'INotifyPropertyChanged' useful? But the 'Graphic' still remains my biggest problem

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to redraw a control (or a part of it), without calling refresh() at every proprieties change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about more complex control, then consider to change `Refresh` to `Invalidate` to invalidate specific regions of your UserControl.
To get `Graphics` object just call `CreateGraphics` method.

Comment: CreateGraphics is good at causing flicker.  The advice should be to use the Graphic object supplied by the paint event.

Comment: @LarsTech question was - how can I get graphics object. `CreateGraphics` is a sure thing. And `Paint` event of cause. But since author already has OnPaint event, then I mentioned `CreateGraphics`.

Comment: Is safe to store e.Graphic in a private variabile and call _graphic.DrawLine (assuming i've done _graphic=e.Graphic inside OnPaint) at every proprieties change?

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't do it. Since all your painting happens in `OnPaint` event you have `Graphics` object there already.

Comment: And so...can I call OnPaint by myself inside a proprieties?

Comment: `Invalidate` coupled with `Update` and `Refresh` do that. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/subhagpo/archive/2005/02/22/378098.aspx